# Book on advanced topics of Network Flows

Tags: reference-request, optimization, linear-programming, network-flow

I am taking linear optimization class. Could you suggest me good fundamental textbook on advanced topics of network flows. To be more specific I am interested in: *Multicommodity flow and multicut, the flow/cut gap theorem, algorithm CKR/FRT, concarent flow and sparse cut, embedding graph metrics into random trees*.

Before stating **network flows**, I was using few great books on operations reseach and linear programming. But none of them covers such topics. Vanderbei's and Rader's book end up on max-flow min-cut theorem, Bazaraa's book goes further and covers multicommodity flows.

Comment: Good paper on very advanced level was found here [An improved approximation algorithm for the 0-extension problem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.123.2508), enough for motivation, but if you know an explanation on lower lever maybe video lecture, I will appreciate posting a link.

Comment: [The Design of Approximation Algorithms](http://www.designofapproxalgs.com/), [Approximation Algorithms](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN3540653678)

Comment: The classic text on network flows is *Network Flows*, by Ahuja, Magnanti, and Orlin.  It's about 20 years old, though.  I don't know of a more recent text.

Answer (score 1):

Great question.

Try this:

[R.T. Rockafellar, Network Flows and Monotropic Optimization, J. Wiley, (1984).](http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr-NetworkFlows.pdf)

Rockafellar is a reknowned expert in optimisation.  His books and materials are excellent examples of clarity and build quickly from an overview to advanced topics in network theory.

If you go to [his website](http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/mypage.html), he has kindly made the [full text of this book](http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr-NetworkFlows.pdf) and many of his papers and course lecture notes available as PDF downloads.